# How to configure Grails plugin to override Log4J settings for "parent" apps?

Tags: grails, configuration, log4j, grails-plugin

I'm writing a Grails plugin that will impose very specific log4j settings (in its own `log4j.xml`), and I would like to configure it such that an app which uses this plugin is forced to use the plugin's log4j configuration (instead of any log4j configs that the app itself has defined).

For example, let's say I want the plugin to force all downstream Grails apps to log to a file called `/var/log/fizz.log`. How could I make this work?

**Update**: And if it's not possible for the plugin to override the app that uses it, then at the very least I need the app to be able to use the plugin's log4j config without having to define its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the application configuration settings will always trump the plugin settings. You can't avoid that (as far as I know).

However, you can always remove the log4j configuration from the application's config.groovy and make your plugin wire in the log4j configuration within the doWithSpring event of the plugin's lifecycle. This will ensure that the plugin is responsible for configuring log4j.

I will assume you don't need any help wiring up the log4j.xml portion since you didn't ask about that. Just in case, that might look something like this:

MyLoggingPlugin.groovy

```
...
def doWithSpring = {
  ...
      log4jConfigurer(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean){
        targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
        targetMethod = "initLogging"
        arguments = "path/to/log4j.xml"
      }
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore (+1) - is the `log4jConfigurer` object inherently on the classpath, or do I need to include any JARs and instantiate an instance of its class first? If so, can you provide an accurate example of how I would obtain the `log4jConfigurer` instance? Thanks again!

Comment: log4jConfigurer is actually the name of the bean responsible in Spring for configuring log4j. Which Grails is built upon. In my example you are configuring that bean within the Spring application context. Another approach would be to define said bean in your Resources.groovy for your application and read the log4j.xml from your plugin instead.