# Where to put log4j.xml in a Grails app?

Tags: grails, configuration, log4j

Sometimes I see, in a Grails app's `Config.groovy`, something like:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        ...
    }

    root {
        ...
    }

    ...etc.     
}
```

This is clearly a programmatic way of specifying the log4j configs. I'm wondering:

1. Is it possible to specify the log4j configs in a `log4j.xml` file, and then tell the Grails app where to look for it?
2. If so, where should I place the `log4j.xml` inside the Grails app, and how/where do I "connect" it to the app?

Answer (score 2):

Grails by default won't use log4j.xml. You have a few options.

1. Wire up Spring to use log4j.xml. This can be somewhat complex if you aren't familiar with Spring and the required beans. Which you and I [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660006/how-to-configure-grails-plugin-to-override-log4j-settings-for-parent-apps).
2. Use the [Log4j XML plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/log4j-xml) for Grails.

For simple use cases the second option would be preferred.

**Update**

Based on your follow up question in the comments you might be better off configuring logging directly in your plugin using the DSL syntax. Burt [explains how this is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920796/how-do-i-configure-logging-for-a-grails-plugin) in another post.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore (+1) - is it possible to skip the `log4j.xml` altogether? In that other question you just referenced (from yesterday), you have the following: `arguments = "path/to/log4j.xml"`; this is the only reason why I was thinking along the lines of using an actual `log4j.xml` file. **Instead**, would it be possible, inside the plugin's `doWithSpring` event handler, to configure the `log4jConfigurer` using Groovy syntax like I have above in this question? That would cut out the need for a `log4j.xml` file entirely, and still give me the ability to specify log4j configs in the plugin

Comment: See the update to the answer. Since you don't really /need/ to use the log4j.xml that may be an easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Grails automatically excludes any file in `grails-app/conf` that matches `log4j.*`:

From `scripts/_GrailsWar.groovy`:

```
    ant.copy(todir:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes", failonerror:false, preservelastmodified:true) {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf") {
            exclude(name:"*.groovy")
            exclude(name:"log4j.*")
            exclude(name:"**/hibernate/**")
            exclude(name:"**/spring/**")
        }
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf/hibernate", includes:"**/**")
        fileset(dir:"${grailsSettings.sourceDir}/java") {
            include(name:"**/**")
            exclude(name:"**/*.java")
        }
        fileset(dir:"${grailsSettings.sourceDir}/groovy") {
            include(name:"**/**")
            exclude(name:"**/*.groovy")
        }
        fileset(dir:"${resourcesDirPath}", includes:"log4j.properties")
    }
```

As pointed out, there are other ways to achieve what you want without using the `log4j.xml` file, but if you do want to use it, you can add some logic to your `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` to ensure that it gets packaged in your WAR:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(todir:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes", failonerror:false, preservelastmodified:true) {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf") {
            include(name:"log4j.xml")
        }
    }
}
```